# Sharing a single view between two different ASP.NET MVC controller's action methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two controllers: `OneController` and `TwoController`.

Both of these have an `Index()` method and they both return the same `Index.cshtml` view located in location `/View/Shared/Number/Index.cshtml`.

Locally, I'm able to navigate to this path and render the view just fine. 
However, once deployed to the web server, it can't navigate to this path. I'm not sure what would cause it to behave like this.

This is the error I get:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The view
>   '/Views/Shared/Number/Index.cshtml' or its master was not found or no
>   view engine supports the searched locations.

Exact code I'm working with, same actions on both controllers:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
      return View(GetPath("Index"));
 }

 private static string GetPath(string viewName)
 {
      return $"/Views/Shared/Number/{viewName}.cshtml";
 }
```

Comment: Put the view in shared folder

Comment: It is already in the shared folder. /Views/Shared/Number/Index.cshtml

Comment: Mate, remove folder number!

Comment: Your view is in folder number not shared

Comment: Okay I see what you mean. But why would it cause it to not load if it is in fact left in that folder? I mean it loads fine when ran on localhost, but doesn't load when on the web server.

Comment: When a view is not found the error msg is telling you where the app looks for view, so you need to make sure that you place the view in one of the searched locations

Comment: Ok. It makes sense to put the view in any one of the searched locations. So then why would it even load at all if put in an incorrect place when run locally?

Comment: Can you post the Actions?

Comment: Okay. Posted the exact code I'm working with above. Thanks!

Comment: `return View($"~/Views/Shared/Number/{viewName}.cshtml")` try this

Comment: Okay, so after adding ~ in front of the path, now it won't work locally either.  So why was it able to resolve the path when ~ was omitted?

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: I'm sorry, adding ~ in front continues to work locally. Now I will deploy to test and see if it still works. Will update you in a bit.

Comment: Oh man, that was it. Thank you so much!